# What would be "realistic" values for gravity, mass and contact material in cannon.js?

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, cannon.js

i've looked in the cannon.js examples, and they seem to mostly use between -10 and -40 for gravity and something between 1 and 10 for the mass of an object (or CANNON.RigidBody as they are called), these demo objects are "well behaved" with these values in that they are just "heavy" enough to overcome gravity and not so "heavy" that they make the ground plane look fake.. by that i mean that i have tried increasing the masses of falling objects and the more mass they have the more they make the floor look like it is made of marshmallow (i.e. spongy) when they land.
(btw: *yes, i do know that mass and weight are not the same thing* ;-)

gravity is usually 9.8 m/s/s in mathematics so how could that be implemented in CANNON.World.gravity ?

i have found on the internet that the mass of stone is 2515 kilograms/cubic metre, so if i wanted to drop a 1x1x1 metre stone block how would that translate into mass for:

```
var block = new CANNON.RigidBody(mass, shape, material);
```

and then there is this `material` parameter.. would i need to have 2 materials (1 for the floor and 1 for the stone block) and then how would i set the friction coefficient and restitution values for the materials to react when they collide?

i know this seems like many questions, and i'm not aiming for absolute accuracy, just needing guidance because of a) my lack of knowledge with physics and b) not much documentation for those of us trying to use cannon.js who are not physics professors ;-)

the real question is "How to approximate realism" i guess.

cannon.js is great, works really well, and i really appreciate all the hard work that Stefan Hedman ([schteppe](https://github.com/schteppe)) has put into it so far.

Comment: Are you making a game? In that case, having a realistic world is maybe not the best idea. A rather small stone in the real world has great acceleration and you would need large canvas or small objects to be able to show real-life gravity. I'm not sure many players would appreciate that. In games, most objects have much smaller gravity than the same material in real life.

Comment: This would probably fit http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ better.

Comment: here is a [demo](http://j.mp/ZxLj4H), the small block dimensions are 100x100x100, the single large block is 200x200x200, my player characters height is between 100-200 which if we accept 100=1 meter seems about accurate (avg male height 1.75m), i don't know what units cannon.js uses internally to measure box size, i'm just assuming that on the screen, when compared to the players height, the smaller blocks look about 1m cubed and the single large block is 2m cubed. its unrealistic that a man can easily move a solid 1m stone block but he certainly should not be able to move the 2m block.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cannon.js uses the MKS system of units (meter-kilogram-second). To correctly set gravity to 9.8 m/s/s, you do:

```
world.gravity.set(0,-9.8,0);
```

(assuming "up" direction is  along the positive Y axis.)

For the mass calculation, you could do something like this:

```
var density = 2515; // kg/m^3
var mass = density * shape.volume(); // M=p*V
```

Then use this mass when creating your stone bodies.

If you are aiming for a game with real time physics, you may have to let go of the "correct" physical properties to increase physics performance. You can do that by changing gravity and masses, adding damping, limiting maximum velocity of bodies, etc.. There are no specific guidelines for this, but there are a number of tricks.

Regarding materials: In general you create a new `CANNON.Material` for each material you have in your scene. Then you create a `CANNON.ContactMaterial` that defines what happens when a pair of these materials meet. Here's sample code, but see the [friction demo](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/friction.html) for a full example.

```
var slipperyMat = new CANNON.Material();
var friction = 0.0;
var restitution = 0.2;
var slipperyContact = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(slipperyMat,slipperyMat,friction,restitution);
world.addContactMaterial(slipperyContact);
```

If you only plan to have one type of material, you can set properties on the default contact material in the world instead. Have a look at `world.defaultContactMaterial`.

The sponginess question is a good one. If you want to hang on to your physically correct masses, gravity, etc., you probably need to increase precision a bit. You can do that by using a smaller time step (for example, try using two half steps per rendering frame) and/or tweaking the contact solving settings:

```
world.solver.iterations = 20; // Increase solver iterations (default is 10)
world.solver.tolerance = 0;   // Force solver to use all iterations

// Adjust constraint equation parameters: use to tweak sponginess
slipperyContact.contactEquationStiffness = 1e8;
slipperyContact.contactEquationRegularizationTime = 3;
```

The stiffness and regularization controls the "sponginess" of the contacts. If you use large stiffness and small regularization, the solver will try to make less spongy contacts for you. Provided enough solver precision (small time step and lots of iterations), you will get a better solution.

I've assumed Cannon.js 0.6.0 (dev branch at the moment) throughout this answer.

Comment: Using such a high density results in very high masses and very large forces needed to move objects ( > 1000 units ), vs the examples of cannon only uses small masses like `5`. Why the discrepancy?